# how to select programmatically selectable item in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Help me please!
how to select programmatically selectable item in jquery?
I want call mousedown event manullay

```
<div id="Explorer">
<!--items-->
</div>
<input type="button" title="Select" click="Select()"/>
<script>
$("#Explorer").selectable();
function Select() { 
//i know following code is incorrect
$("#Explorer").children().eq(4).select();
}
</script>
```

Comment: No, it's different question

Comment: How it's different? Please explain better maybe we can help.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/selectable/

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/ did you check this if you can see any method which helps your purpose

Comment: I want call mousedown event manullay

Comment: what do you mean by _I want call mousedown event manually_

Comment: Selectable elements only selected by mouse click and can't select manually. For example select selectable element by a button

Answer (score 1):

Several errors in your code:

1- Use of `select()` was wrong.

2- Do not re-declare a function with `select` name

```js
$(function() {
  $("#Explorer").selectable();
});

function my_select() {
  $("#Explorer").find('.item').eq(4).addClass('ui-selected');
}
```

```css
#Explorer .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}

#Explorer .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}

#Explorer {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

#Explorer p {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="Explorer">
  <p class="item">Item 1</p>
  <p class="item">Item 2</p>
  <p class="item">Item 3</p>
  <p class="item">Item 4</p>
  <p class="item">Item 5</p>
  <p class="item">Item 6</p>
  <p class="item">Item 7</p>
</div>

<input type="button" title="Select" onclick="my_select()" value="select" />
```